# How to select multi class with same prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select **multi class** that start with `foo-class-`, i.e. `foo-class-1`, `foo-class-2`, `foo-class-3`...in jQuery ?

Comment: Do you have access to the code that generates the html?  It would be a lot better to include a shared class on each element.

Comment: Give them a common class and avoid the slow work arounds.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev not a duplicate - this is a much harder question because IDs only have a single value, but classes may have multiple (space separated) values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

**CASE 1**: When you have the single class for a element

```
var $class = $('[class^="foo-class-"]');
```

**CASE 2**: When you have multiple classes for a element (*Credit to Adeneo*)

```
var $class = $('[class]').filter(function(){
    return (" " + this.className).indexOf(' foo-class-') != -1;
});
```

Comment: This assumes that this class is the first class listed if there are multiple classes.  This would fail on things like `<div class="abc foo-class-1">`  http://jsfiddle.net/g7YFP/

Comment: @JamesMontagne: http://jsfiddle.net/g7YFP/1/ :)

Comment: That has problems as well, with class names that contain but do not start with the string.  http://jsfiddle.net/g7YFP/2/  Also, that isn't the answer you posted.

Comment: @James Montagne: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: just replace "!= -1" with "== 0" http://jsfiddle.net/g7YFP/3/

Comment: @user1912285 It will not work again for this case http://jsfiddle.net/g7YFP/4/. Here's the solution http://jsfiddle.net/g7YFP/5/

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Is it ok now?? http://jsfiddle.net/g7YFP/5/

Comment: @PalashMondal Seems to match all the cases now.

Comment: But how do I apply this to drag-drop items (using jQueryUI), I created codes here but it wont work: http://jsfiddle.net/mQYF4/

Comment: @user1912285: See this http://jsfiddle.net/mQYF4/3/ Issue was in the `z - index: 5`. It should be `zIndex: 5` :)

Answer (score 2):

[**SEE HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("[class^='foo-class']")
```

You can specify whatevere the attribute you want in place of `class`

Comment: Just hope there is not another class before the foo one.

Comment: Thank!, that means i can use it in `items.droppable({
  accept: "[class^='foo-class']",
  activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
   foo_function( ui.draggable );
  }
 });` ? (jQueryUI)

Comment: sorry  i am not sure on that.Try once and let me know

Comment: I tried to apply your code but it dont work: http://jsfiddle.net/mQYF4/

Answer (score 2):

```
var foos = $('*', parent_selector).filter(function() {
              return (" " + this.className).indexOf(' foo-class-') != -1;
           });
```

Comment: and what if the class name _isn't_ preceded by a space?

Comment: would fail `class="foo-class-x"`

Answer (score 0):

If there is any chance that your `class=""` attribute has multiple classes, then you'd probably be best off rolling out a custom `.filter()` selection instead.

Here I'm using a regular expression to filter out elements that have a class value that has `foo-class-`. My regex is rusty though, so I'm sure that that is sub-optimal, but you should get the gist.

```
var candidates = $('div'); // or some preliminary selection
var finalists = candidates.filter(function () {
    return !!/\bfoo-class-.*/.exec(this.className);
});
```

Comment: This "contains" as opposed to "starts with".

Comment: @JamesMontagne ~ like I said, rusty.

Comment: @JamesMontagne ~ updated. hopefully that fares better? :D